# Why can const int& bind to an int?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

In the C++ primer, I found that `const int &` can bind with a int object.I don't understand that,because I think `const int &` should bind with a `const int` not a `int` object, the `int` object can change, the book explain this question for that when the `const int &` object bind with `int`; there is a temporary object between the two, for example:

```
int a=0;
const int &r=a;
```

We can use `b` as the temporary value, so above is equal that:

```
const int b=a;
const int &r=b;
```

But I think the book is not right, because if  there is a temporary like `b` existing between `a` and `r`,the value of `r` can't be changed, but when I debug the following coding in visual studio, I found it is not right:

```
int a=0;
const int &r=a;
a=3;
cout<<r<<endl;
```

The output is that `r=3;` the value of `r` can be changed, why? I don't understand that.

Comment: `r` is not being changed, it's just a reference. By making the reference const, it means the reference can't change the object, and not that the object the reference binds to can't change, that would be extremely rigid.

Comment: References have the value of whatever it is they are referencing. If that thing changes, so too will the value of the reference. A const reference is simply a reference that can't be modified, so it can't change the thing it is referencing.

Comment: A `const int &`  is a reference that won't be used to logically change `int` it references.    In your first example, the compiler will not allow `r` to be used to change `a`, but doesn't stop `a` itself from being changed directly.  Try doing `r = 42` and watch the compiler complain bitterly - in all your samples.

Comment: You can always add `const` as it is more restrictive.  Removing `const` should only be done when you really know what you are doing.

Comment: thank you ,I have thoughted that reference is like a pointer .

Comment: @karel it is almost the same as pointer (in many cases reference is implemented as pointer). You can do `const int *p = &a;`

Comment: @karel Welcome on StackOverflow. I noticed you posted many "thank you" comments below. On StackOverflow, you shouldn't -- comment only if you want really add something. To reward good answers, you can upvote them. After some time since you post a question, you are also expected to "accept" the answer which was most helpful.

Answer (score 19):

> don't understand that,because I think `const int &` should bind with a `const int` not a `int` object

You are mistaken. A reference-to-const (const reference in short) doesn't mean that only const objects can be bound. It means that the object can not be modified through the reference.

What is not allowed would be to bind a non-const reference to a const object, because such reference could be used to modify the object which would break the constness.

> the value of `r` can be changed, why?

The object that `r` refers to was modified - which is OK because the object isn't const. `r` still refers to the same object and the object was not modified using `r`.

Having a const reference does not mean that the referred object can not change. It means that the object can not be changed using that reference.

If you wish to have an object that can not change, then that object itself has to be const. A const reference does not make the referred object const. The book has shown you how to create a const object:

```
const int b=a;
```

> I have regarded reference as poiter mistakely,because they are similiar some time.

Indeed, references are very similar to pointers. Regarding the context of this question, they behave similarly. A demo:

```
int a=0;
const int *r=&a;
a=3;
cout<<*r<<endl;
```

Comment: The one adjustment I'd make to the answer is that there really isn't a "constant object" *per se* in C++. Even with something like `const Type b=a`, the object accessible by the variable `b` can change if Type has a mutable data member, or if someone `const_cast`s a pointer/reference to it. (Though doing so may invoke odd/undefined behavior.) -- `const` never really tells you about the object, it's only telling you about the variable you're accessing the object through.

Comment: @R.M. I think this is going a bit out of the scope of the question, but there "really" are constant objects in C++. Constness is simply defined in terms of non-mutable data members. We just decide to not care whether the mutable members are modified. Even in the sense that not even mutable members could be modified, there are such objects: any const object with no mutable members. None of the fundamental types have any members of any kind for example.

Comment: @R.M. The object and the variable are very much tied to each other. If the variable is const, then the object (except the mutable members) may not be modified, not even by "going around" the variable. Whether such guarantee doesn't hold when the program has UB is pointless consideration. If there is UB, then there are no guarantees about anything.

Comment: @user2079303 I think real question is if there are really const objects. C++ is a language that can describe a model and one of it's keyword const can describe a non mutable object. But the model is just a ideal description of reality and everything that is outside of model that c++ describe, may change the reality itself. To be more specify the is no way to protect data from changes from outside application scope.

Comment: @Logman I don't think there can be "really" const objects in any language. If your object is stored in memory, and cosmic radiation flips a bit, then its value can change regardless of the rules of your language. The rules of C++ apply only to C++ code. No C++ program is allowed to modify its const objects. And All C++ programs are allowed to assume that their const objects do not change by outside influence. Therefore even if the cosmic flip happens, your program might not even notice since it might not bother to read the value from memory due to constness assumption. But it might notice...

Answer (score 7):

`const` in this example only guarantee that `a` can not be changed where `r` is used. Usually this is used for functions that do not change input parameters like:

```
int doNotModifyFoo(const int &foo);
```

Comment: thank you ,I have regarded reference as poiter mistakely,because they are similiar some time.I have seen the follow coding in primer C++: const int *p=&a;the value which p points can not change,so p can't point to a int object,so I make a mistake,I have thought the value which a const reference points can not change.

Comment: @karel in this regard, references behave the same as pointers.

Answer (score 4):

An object cannot be modified "through" a `const` reference or a pointer to `const` of it. But a `const` reference or pointer to `const` doesn't impose any kind of run-time lock on the underlying object and (assuming it was not declared `const`) the original declaration or any non-`const` reference or pointer to non-`const` can still be used to modify it.

Indeed if the object was not originally declared `const` then `const`-ness can be cast away and used to modify the underlying object.

Indeed even if the object was originally declared `const` this may be possible (but is implementation dependent).

`const` is a way of indicating that a function (or functions) shouldn't modify an object (either as an argument in our return value out or declaration).

It doesn't (in general) mean the object can't be modified through that or some other reference/pointer.

It also not possible to modify what a reference refers to. Or at least there is no valid way of doing it. In some circumstances it is possible in practice by jiggery pokery of obtaining an address of where a reference is held and modifying it like a pointer. That will usually fail in some circumstances because references are often optimized out of existence and because the compiler knows they 'cannot be modified' such violations might only be partially successful.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you can refer to non-const objects with references and/or pointers to const.

```
int x = 10;
const int& r = x; //OK
const int* p = &x; //OK
```

Of course, since x is not constant it can be changed. However, what you're basically saying by having a const reference to a non-const object is: **I will not change this object *via this reference/pointer***. You still can change the object directly or through other references or pointers.

Think of it as a read-only handle. Yes, the object itself may be mutable, but in many cases you may be willing to acquire and/or provide  only a read-only access to that otherwise mutable variable.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int a=0;
> const int &r=a;
> a=3;
> cout<<r<<endl;
> ```
>
> The output is that r=3; the value of r can be changed, why? I don't
>   understand that.

The `const` only applies to the reference `r`. It means that you can't change whatever `r` binded to via `r`. You can't do:

```
r = 3;
```

That will be an error, because `r` is a `const int&` and cannot be modified. For now you can think of references as some sort of lightweight transparent "proxy" of an object. So if the "proxy" is `const`, you cannot modify the object through the "proxy". However, it doesn't mean the original object cannot be modified.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `const int & r` promises not to mutate the value it's referencing. This is a stronger guarantee than `int &`. So, it's possible to refer to an `int` using a `const int &` reference. But you may not modify it. It's a subset of the operations possible on the value. However, it's not true the other way around, if you were trying to get a `int &` reference to an `const int` value, it would result in a compiler error because the value itself is immutable, and you are trying to get a mutable reference to this immutable value. The operations possible on the `int &` reference are a superset of what's possible on `const int` value.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the variable `a` which is `0` initially is holded at memory.

If you write later: `a=5`, it'll set that value in memory to `5`.

When you write a reference `const int & r = a;` you are only saying that `r` should access that same place in memory where `5` is being hold.
[image]

Because `a` is not `const` it can modify the value.

This is **basically** how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things: 
Const and reference.

Reference is just another name for same memory unit. You can use any name to change the value held at that memory.

A **const** reference is denoted in C++ by a code like

```
int j =2; 
int const &i = j; //or Alternatively
const int &i = j;
```

**There is no restriction which makes the referred object to be constant as well.**

Here, you can not use **i** to change value of **j**. However this does not make the memory location **j** to be constant.You can peacefully change the value of **j**.

```
j =3
//but i = 3 will raise an error saying 
//assignment of read-only reference ‘i’
```